# Solving exponential equations in python

Tags: python, math, equation, exponential

I made a function that converts letters into numbers (a=1,b=2,etc...) Then I do this equation on them:

```
b^(a / (b/2))
b = letter being translated
a = previous letter (or if b is the first letter, a = len(string)
```

for example, here is how you would translate the letter 'e':

```
'Hello' = [34, 5, 12, 12, 15]
5^(34 / (5/2)) = 3206210698.73506
```

Here is the code I used to do this:

```
alphabet = {
'H' : 34,
'e' : 5,
'l' : 12,
'o' : 15,
}   
entry = "Hello"
password = []
hashed = []
firstNumber = True
lengthPower = len(entry)
counter = 0

for letter in entry:

    key = alphabet[letter]
    password.append(key)

for number in password:
    if firstNumber:
        powered = number ** lengthPower
        lastNumber = number
        firstNumber = False
    else:
        powered = number ** (password[counter]/(number/2))
        lastNumber = number
        counter += 1
    hashed.append(powered)
```

But how can I reverse this operation?  '3206210698.73506' back into 5 ('e')?

```
b^(34 / (b/2)) = 3206210698.73506
```

Answer (score 0):

When `y = x ^ n`, `x = y ^ (1/n)`. See [this](http://wmueller.com/precalculus/newfunc/invpwr.html) or google 'inverse of power'. So in your case, this will guide you.

```
n = 34/(5/2)
y = pow(5, n)  # 3206210698.7350655
x = int(pow(y, 1/n))  # 5
```